# SQL Server : check boolean can only occur once as true

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I have a table with `[Id]`, `[Name]` and `[bDefault]`. All the columns are **not nullable**.

Is it possible with a check that `bDefault` can only be true for **one** record? Making it a unique index won't work, since only max 1 record will be true, all the rest will be false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a filtered unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_... ON [Table](bDefault) WHERE bDefault = 1
```

Comment: 5 minutes till I can accept. Thanks a lot, haven't heard of filtered unique indexes before. Off topic; this is not create-able throughout the UI of 2008, is it?

Comment: @IvanM: Management Studio support for filtered indexes is present in Management Studio 2014, at least (the "filter" tab of the "new index" dialog), but I don't know about earlier versions. The feature itself was added in SQL Server 2008, so it's possible SSMS lagged (I never use it to create database objects myself).

Comment: I think you can do this in SQL2012 also but not 2008R2.

Comment: Yeah, if it's throughout the 'Manage Indexes and Keys' then it's indeed not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to sql-server 2008 it is possible to prevent having duplicate values using triggers. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx(a bit)

go

CREATE TRIGGER xxx_trg
ON xxx
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
as
IF exists
  (SELECT 1
   FROM xxx
   WHERE a = 1
   GROUP BY a
   HAVING count(*) > 1
  )
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Already exists', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK transaction;
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right, the comments let me to believe that filtered index was not possible in 2008. I have corrected my query to only disallow 1