# How to have a column at `true` for only one in several linked rows, and the rest at `false`?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've looked around and found questions similar to mine but not quite the same so obviously the answers they got didn't really suit mine :(

To try and paint the whole picture I have a database with amongst others, a "users" table, each user has one or more phone numbers in another table "phone_Number". A user has a main phone number so I tried to solve it by adding a boolean column 'main_Number' to the phone_Number table but I haven't been able to find a way to make sure that of all the rows of a user only one has that column at 'true'

[Edit] : To be more precise the "phone_numbers" table records can be ordered by the 'user_Id' and in each record group (user_Id group) there will be one and only one main_number at 'true'. Therefore there will be as many 'main_number' at 'true' as there are users

Is there a way to do that?

On the similar questions that I found the general answer was to go with another table that points to the main number's row. But doing that I'm obviously unable to retrieve with one query all the rows of a user (including the column in the third table), unless it's my request who is wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thx

Comment: You can create a function that accepts as parameters the userId and the phone_Number (on phone_Number_Id). The function updates all the main_Number values for the user to false, and then set to true the passed phone_Number.

Comment: This is a common problem that's not easily solved with mere constraints. It's possible in some DBMS, but I don't know whether in MySQL. A simpel solution is to give the user table a redundant main_phone column. That's easy to implement, but can lead to inconsistencies of course.

Comment: @NicolaLepetit : That was the solution i thought of using with java before updating the database but i found it a little heavy so i thought i'd ask for another solution :) Thx for your hint :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I did it at first when i had only one phone number per user, but now like you said it feels redundant to have a phone number in the user table :) thx for your hint :-)

Comment: This could theoretically be implemented using a "partial index". Unfortunately MySQL does not implement them (in MySQL lingo there's a partial index, but refers to a different concept). As a reference, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and even SQLite do support partial indexes, but not MySQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler : It's indeed unfortunate that MySQL doesn't implement them. Never heard of them though ("partial index") i'll look into it and maybe find a way with it :)Thx for your input :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : check boolean can only occur once as true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720050/sql-server-check-boolean-can-only-occur-once-as-true)

Comment: @EliadL : Not exactly, in that scenario you can only have one row at 'true' but in mine there will be multiple. To be more precise the "phone_numbers" table records can be ordered by the 'user_Id' and in each record group (user_Id group) there will be one and only one main_number at 'true'.
Therefore there will be as many 'main_number' at 'true' as there are users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flag Records with highest version number within calculated field/calculated column as “true”, rest as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553410/flag-records-with-highest-version-number-within-calculated-field-calculated-colu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky. Here is why:

You want each user to have exactly one main phone number. So, if a user has only one phone number, this is the main number. If a user has four numbers, then one must be the main number, the others secondary numbers.

**... At least at the time of COMMIT to the table!**

Let's say a user has two entries. 123456 is the main number 654321 a secondary one. Now the user wants 654321 to become their main number.

This must work:

```
start transaction;
update user_phone set main = true where number = '654321';
-- Just for this microsecond there are two main numbers for this user.
update user_phone set main = false where number = '123456';
commit;
-- The user has one main number again.
```

And this:

```
start transaction;
update user_phone set main = false where number = '123456';
-- Just for this microsecond there are only secondary numbers for this user.
update user_phone set main = true where number = '654321';
commit;
-- The user has one main number again.
```

But not this:

```
start transaction;
update user_phone set main = true where number = '654321';
commit;
-- There are two main numbers now for the user.
```

or this:

```
start transaction;
update user_phone set main = false where number = '123456';
commit;
-- There are only secondary numbers now for the user.
```

In some DBMS you could solve this with deferred constraints, i.e. constraints that only apply on COMMIT. In the users table you'd have a main phone ID additionally to your phone table then and you'd insert a user, then their phones, then update the user with their main phone in one transaction. On COMMIT all data would be consistent. If not, the violated foreign key constraint would fire. MySQL doesn't feature deferred constraints.

Here is how I would solve this: Give the phone numbers a rank. This can be 1, 2, 3, ... or 10, 20, 30, ... It doesn't actually matter; you'd consider the lowest rank number the main phone.

```
create table user_phone
(
  user_id int         not null,
  phone   varchar(20) not null,
  prio    int         not null,
  unique (user_id, phone),
  unique (user_id, prio)
);
```

The related query:

```
select 
  user_id, phone,
  case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by prio) = 1
       then 'main'
       else 'secondary'
  end as type
from user_phone
order by user_id, type;
```

If you want to make another phone the main phone, then just change the ranks. E.g.

```
update user_phone set prio = prio + 1 where user_id = 1;
-- Still the same order, still the same main number.
update user_phone set prio = 1 where user_id = 1 and phone = '54321';
-- Phone '54321' is the new main number for user 1.
```

The analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` requires MySQL version 8. It isn't available in earlier versions.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8a483f769db850f90cc4a6059e59832

Comment: Exactly what i need :-) Just got to change to MySQL v8 since i'm on v5.7 now. Thx for your time

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to choose from.

> Option1: "Main_phone" column in users table

Just add this column to the table and code assuming it as main phone and data in "phone_Number" table as others phones available.

*Pros:* Easy to implement. Not so hard to mantain. Discarc "main_number" column in phone_Numbers table

*Cons:* When retreiving all phones you'l need a join, which would kill all index uses and performance of query. It would be problematic if your tables are so big

> Option 2: Triggers on Not phone_Numbers table

Add "main_number" column as you proposed.
Code some triggers before-insert, before-update, before-delete to control your restriction.

**Before-insert:**

Should control your restriction

**Before update:**

Should control your restriction.
Should control what happens if you delete the "main telephone" row for that user (if necessary).

**Before delete:**

Should control what happens if you delete the "main telephone" row for that user (if necessary).

*Pros:* Easy to retrieve, easy to mantain (once developed)

*Cons:* Hard to code.

Comment: Thx for the input, feels like the trigger would perfectly answer to my problem here. Now to implement it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a comment that does not fit in the comments section.

Even though MySQL does not support partial indexes, I wanted to show how to do it in PostgreSQL (Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite also) so you know it's possible.

For example:

```
create table users (
  id int not null,
  phone varchar(10) not null,
  main_number boolean not null
);

create unique index ix1 on users (id, main_number) where main_number;

insert into users (id, phone, main_number) values (1, '123', true);
insert into users (id, phone, main_number) values (1, '456', false);
insert into users (id, phone, main_number) values (1, '789', false); -- succeeds
insert into users (id, phone, main_number) values (1, '468', true); -- fails
```

As you see, the third insert succeeds since multiple `false` values are allowed per `id`. However, the fourth insert fails since only one `true` value is allowed per `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a unique constraint and a generated column.

```
alter table t add is_main_number boolean
    generated always as (case when main_number then 1 end);
```

Then you can use this in a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_user_number_main on t(user_id, is_main_number)
```

MySQL allows duplicates for `NULL` values in unique indexes, so this does what you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc15f19de6608f068fc1175a88207e40) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Not quite what i want :-) With your answer when inserting or updating, all data which would have the column 'main_number' at true will have the column 'is_main_number' at 1. What i want is that it be impossible for 2 row of the same user to "be" the main number at the same time, meaning unless all rows are 'not' the main number, no number can become the main number (via insert or update)

Comment: @six-one . . . If you want the uniqueness per user, then you just use that for the unique index.  Your question doesn't have sample data, so it is a little hard to follow exactly what you are asking.

Comment: It may be that i didn't use your answer correctly then :-). But to try and be more precise, The Impaler gave an aswer and in it he showed at the end how some insert would succeed or fail, those cases are exactly what i'm aiming for, but when i used your answer, that last case that should have failed, didn't.

Comment: @six-one . . .  Except for the detail that that syntax does not work in MySQL:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4d527c3edd4d48585123add82a4e7ce.  I added a db<>fiddle to show that this does work.

Comment: Yep, like both of you said, he's answer wouldn't work on MySQL since it doesn't support partial indexes. I was just talking about the insert he made to try and explain the behaviour i'm aiming for.

Comment: @six-one . . . That is why I added the db<>fiddle to the answer.